# Putty SSH to Raspberry Pi: 'Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection'

Tags: ssh, putty, raspberry-pi

I tried to connect my Raspberry Pi via Putty SSH, but it kept showing the error

> Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection

It's a bit weird because when I ping my Pi's IP address in CMD, it works well, which means my Pi could definitely connect to my laptop.

I've got SSH enabled on my Pi, and 'TCP keepalives' enabled on my putty. I also tried to make the value of 'Seconds between keepalives' a bit longer, but end up with time out.

Any ideas of what might be going wrong?

Comment: *"I've got SSH enabled on my Pi"* - How do you manage your Pi, if you cannot connect to it?

Comment: I can connect it directly to screen or use VNC

Comment: OK, so did you check sshd log file?

Comment: Not yet, is there anything needing to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using `ls -l /etc/ssh` what I found is my several key files on server have 0 bits, which doesn't look right. Finally I resolve this by deleting my key files and regenerating them... Looks like some people solve similar problems to mine in the same ways.

```
rm /etc/ssh/sshd_host_*
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```